# Using chaos-monkey-spring-boot together with db-scheduler: getting BeanDefinitionOverrideException

Tags: spring-boot-chaos-monkey

Using the latest version of chaos-monkey-spring-boot (v2.5.4) together with db-scheduler-spring-boot-starter (v10.3, see https://github.com/kagkarlsson/db-scheduler), I get an exception when starting the application:

```
The bean 'scheduler', defined in class path resource [de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/ChaosMonkeyConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/github/kagkarlsson/scheduler/boot/autoconfigure/DbSchedulerAutoConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

Unfortunately, both libraries use a bean with the too generic name 'scheduler'. Bean definition overriding is not an option, it causes other problems.

Do you have any ideas how I can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Chaos Monkey Spring Boot Maintainer here. As you analyzed correctly both libraries expose the same beans.

It came already up in [our issue tracker](https://github.com/codecentric/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/issues/292) and has been fixed and will be released with the soon to be upcoming chaos monkey 2.6.0 release.

EDIT: Its released https://github.com/codecentric/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.6.1